# Simpson correspondence for perverse sheaves

Tags: hodge-theory, perverse-sheaves, higgs-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective complex manifold. Then Simpson's correspondence from nonabelian Hodge theory shows that the category of semisimple local systems on $X$ is equivalent to the category of polystable Higgs bundles with vanishing Chern classes (Cor. 4, p.152, [Introduction to Nonabelian Hodge Theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4939-2830-9_5)). I am wondering what should correspond to the category of semisimple perverse sheaves on $X$.

Comment: They should correspond to some sort of perverse Higgs bundles. You can look at papers of Sabbah and T. Mochizuki for more precise statements in this direction.